# Why do my below cells no longer center after using \multicolumn?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I've got the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Letzter Zustand} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Nächster Zustand} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ausgang}            \\
            &                               & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x = 0$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x = 1$} & $x = 0$ & $x = 1$ \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        $A$ & $B$                           & $A$     & $B$               & $A$ & $B$                    & $y$     & $y$    \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        0   & 0                             & 0       & 0                 & 0   & 1                      & 0       & 0      \\
        0   & 1                             & 1       & 1                 & 0   & 1                      & 0       & 0      \\
        1   & 0                             & 1       & 0                 & 0   & 0                      & 0       & 1      \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the cells below the multicolumns are no longer centering correctly, but rather they appear to be left-aligned. This is most clearly seen in the two columns on the left (First A B), and is also quite noticeable in the 5th-6th column (Third A B).

[image: My Table]

What's causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: it is centred but the heading is making the last spanned column in each group over-wide., the first column is just the width of A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

The issue arises because of the 2- and 4-column `\multicolumn` items are wider than the combined natural widths of the underlying columns.

To resolve it, I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment, set its overall width to something like `0.9\textwidth` -- the optimal value will depend on things like the fontsize and the width of the text block -- and use a centered version of the `X` column type for all eight columns.

[image]

Note also that I've reorganized some of the horizontal rules in the header portion of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{@{}*{8}{C}@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Letzter Zustand} & 
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Nächster Zustand} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Ausgang} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8}
    & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x = 0$} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x = 1$} 
      & $x = 0$ & $x = 1$ \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    \cmidrule(lr){7-7}\cmidrule(l){8-8}
    $A$ & $B$ & $A$ & $B$ & $A$ & $B$ & $y$ & $y$    \\
    \midrule
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0      \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0      \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1      \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this better?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, makecell, booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\smash{\makecell[t]{Letzter\\ Zustand}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{Nächster Zustand}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ausgang} \\
            & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x = 0$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x = 1$} & $x = 0$ & $x = 1$ \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        $A$ & $B$ & $A$ & $B$ & $A$ & $B$ & $y$ & $y$ \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]